# Событие завершение консольного приложения с++

Tags: c++, winapi, события

В программе выделяется `HANDLE` под файл. Если завершить программу до того, как выполнение дойдет до строки с освобождением хендла, хендл ведь не освободиться сам? Есть ли способ задать функцию при прекращении работы?

Comment: При выполнении процедуры освобождения процесса - хандлы сами освобождаются системой. Если у вас нет "особых" случаев (кросс-процессовое взаимодейтвие) то всё будет ок.

Comment: Если проблема с сохранением файла - добавляйте Flush

Comment: Не знаю можно ли перехватить вызов TerminateProcess, можно перехватить нажатие на крестик, можно перехватить Ctrl+C. Можно добавить обработчик в конец main/WinMain. Уточните нужно ли всёещё событие, и до какой степени сложности.